# $\int\sec^3x\,dx$; the integral of a function raised to some power is equal to a fraction of the sum of its integral and its derivative.

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

While looking at the solution

$$\int\sec^3x\,dx \,=\, \frac 12\ln|\sec x + \tan x|\,+\,\frac 12 \sec x \tan x+C\,,$$ 
from integration by parts, I see that $\frac d{dx}\sec x$ is formed by both $u=\sec x$ and $v=\tan x$ when we let $\int\sec^3x\,dx=\int u\,dv$ so
$$\int\sec^3x\,dx \,=\, \frac 12\left(\int\sec x\,dx\,+\,\frac d{dx}\sec x\right)+C\,.$$

I find that this is a simple way to remember the result from now on (and avoid having to evaluate the integral to convince myself) but I wonder *why* such a nice result happens with this integral and

> *is it trivial that the integral of a function raised to some power is equal to a fraction of the sum of its integral and its derivative*?

Why does this happen with this particular integral and are there other  interesting examples of similar behavior?

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Just for clarity, you're asking if/when $uv = u^\prime$?

Comment: @WillCraig I mean that the integral of the function cubed is equal to half the integral of the function plus half the derivative of the function. Now that I wrote it this way I see that it sound much better, I will edit the question I agree that it is not quite clear right now, thank you.

Comment: Oh I see that now. That's much more interesting.

Comment: This a product of the over all method known as the reduction formula for secant, you can actually work out the more general case. There is in fact a whole Wikipedia article written specifically for this particular integral https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the derivative of both sides of 
$$\int\sec^3(x)\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int\sec(x)\ dx+\frac{d}{dx}\sec(x) \right)$$
shows that $\sec(x)$ satisfies the differential equation:
$$y^3 = \frac{1}{2}(y+y'').$$
Now, we can are in a position to generalize this; we can search for solutions to the differential equation
$$y^n=\frac{1}{k}(y+y'')\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad y'' = ky^n-y = f(y)$$
for $k>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. This is a [second order autonomous ODE](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Second-order_first-degree_autonomous_differential_equation), and has the following implicit solution:
    $$K\pm x = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\displaystyle C+2\int f(y)\ dy}}\ dy = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2k}{n+1}y^{n+1}-y^2+C}}\ dy$$
for $C$ and $K$ arbitrary constants. In the case where $n=3$, $k=2$, $C=K=0$, and we take positive $x$ on the left we have the solution
    $$x = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^4-y^2}}\ dy = \int\frac{1}{|y|\sqrt{y^2-1}}\ dy = \operatorname{arcsec}(y)+A$$
and therefore $y=\sec(x-A)$. When $K=0$, the left hand side is $-x$, and $n=3$, $k=2$, and $C=0$, we have
    $$x = \int\frac{-1}{\sqrt{y^4-y^2}}\ dy = \int\frac{-1}{|y|\sqrt{y^2-1}}\ dy = \operatorname{arccsc}(y)+A$$
and so $y=\csc(x-A)$. Taking $f(y) = y-ky^n$ will give you things like David Quinn's second example. Maybe the masters of integration around here will have more to say about integrals of the form: 
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2k}{n+1}y^{n+1}-y^2+C}}\ dy.$$

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the insight!

Comment: @InfiniteMonkey Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

Following a similar pattern, $$\int\csc^3x dx=\frac 12\left(\int csc x dx+\frac{d}{dx}\csc x\right)$$

On a similar theme, $$\int \operatorname{sech}^3x dx=\frac 12\left(\int\operatorname{sech} xdx\color{red}{-}\frac {d}{dx}\operatorname{sech} x\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be asking when $uv = u^\prime$. We can solve this as follows (we let $u = u(t), v = v(t)$);

$$ uv = \dfrac{du}{dt} \implies v dt = \dfrac{du}{u} \implies \int vdt = \int \dfrac{du}{u} \implies \ln{|u|} + C = \int vdt$$

This suggests that such convenient properties occur whenever the antiderivative of $v$ is expressible as a logarithm. In the case given, we have that $\int \tan{t}dt = -\ln{|cos{x}|} + C$. I am not aware of any other integrals that work this way that are not either trivial ($v = 1/t$) or essentially the same as this ($u = \csc{t}, v = \cot{t}$) but if anyone else is aware of some I would love to see!

Answer (score 0):

We can consider the reduction formula:

$$I_n=\int sec^n(x)dx \ s.t. \ n>2$$

Expressing $sec^nx=sec^{n-2}x\cdot sec^2x$ we have:

$$I_n=\int (sec^{n-2}(x)sec^2(x))dx$$

Integrating by parts, and setting $f=sec^{n-2}(x)$ and $g'=sec^2(x)$,

$$I_n=sec^{n-2}(x)tan^2(x)-(n-2)\int (sec^{n-2}(x)tan^2(x))dx$$

$$=sec^{n-2}(x)tan^2(x)-(n-2)\int (sec^{n-2}(x)(sec^2(x)-1))dx$$

$$=sec^{n-2}(x)tan^2(x)-(n-2)(I_n-I_{n-2})$$

Solving for $I_n$, we get:

$$I_n=\frac {sec^{n-1}(x)sin(x)}{n-1}+\frac {n-2}{n-1}I_{n-2}$$

So as $n$ increases, we get a summation of terms including only $sec^{n-2}(x)tan(x)$ and integrals of $sec$, two degrees below the previous integration.